# Why Event Stream in event sourcing pattern?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, microservices, event-sourcing

Wanted to ensure I had clarity on just stripping out things randomly.

**EVENT STORE Database**

```
| p_key | invoice_id | Event type        | Version | Data |
|-------|------------|-------------------|---------|------|
| 1     | 41234      | Invoice_Generated | 1       | JSON |
| 2     | 34241      | Invoice_Generated | 1       | JSON |
| 3     | 12345      | Invoice_Generated | 1       | JSON |
| 4     | 12345      | Invoice_Reviewed  | 2       | JSON |
| 5     | 12345      | Invoice_Paid      | 3       | JSON |
```

JAVA side components

1. Event Store:
2. Event Stream
3. Event

Event store is responsible to both retrieve list of events and save the events to database when everything is done.

```
public interface EventStore {
    EventStream loadEventStream(AggregateId aggregateId);
    void store(AggregateId aggregateId, long version, List<Event> events);

}
```

Event is essentially one of rows retrieved from the database.

```
public interface Event<T> {
    AggregateId getAggregateId();

    int getVersion();

    String getEventType();

    void applyOn(T account);
}
```

what I do not get is the use of event stream. It makes no sense to me as to why would I need an event stream

```
public interface EventStream extends Iterable<Event> {
    long version();

    void addAll(List<Event> changes);
}
```

Is the sole purpose of event stream to give ability to iterate over list of events that does not sound so useful maybe I am missing something but why can't I just get rid of event stream and call it a day?

Source: https://github.com/Pragmatists/eventsourcing-java-example/tree/excercise_1_solution/eventsourcing/src/main/java/com/pragmatists/eventsourcing

Comment: The pragmatists APIs may not be the best starting point for understanding the motivation of the different abstractions.  In this context, it's hard to identify the core of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This questions is about a very low level view of Event sourcing and depends a lot on the actual implementation of an Event store. All-in-all, I can give you an answer, hoping to shed some light on your understanding of Event stores.*

> Is the sole purpose of event stream to give ability to iterate over list of events that does not sound so useful maybe I am missing something but why can't I just get rid of event stream and call it a day?

Yes, an Event stream provides a mean to iterate over a possible large list of events, without retrieving all of them from the Event store in a blocking way. In general it is used only to read events, so its interface does not contain methods to append events to the Event store.

So, the client code needs only the events from the stream.

When adding events to an Event store, in order to protect from concurrent writes, one needs to pass the expected version of the Event stream. One can do this by using a `version` parameter to the method `EventStore.appendEvents(expectedVersion, newEvents)` or it can pass the previously loaded event stream and let the Event store retrieve the last seen `version`, thus reducing the coupling of the client code to the actual implementation of event stream locking mechanism. So, the signature of the appending method could be like this:

```
EventStore.appendEvents(previousEventStream, newEvents)
```

So, the  client code doesn't know/care what locking mechanism (optimistic or pesimistic) is the Event store using to protect from concurrent writes.

One example of this can be found [here](https://github.com/xprt64/dudulina/blob/master/src/Dudulina/EventStore.php) *(disclaimer: it's mine)*:

```
public function appendEventsForAggregate(AggregateDescriptor $aggregateDescriptor, $eventsWithMetaData, AggregateEventStream $expectedEventStream): void;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the richness of the data contained in the JSON field - various interesting forms of stream processing can be performed - e.g. calculating life time value per customer (as you iterate over each event, keep aggregating total spend against specific customer), category-wise spend aggregates (same as above only aggregates are done per item category) etc. Handling the data as a stream helps build lifetime as well as window abstractions (sliding/fixed-width).